# How to analyse and compare a correlation between two variables over time between two groups?

Tags: regression, correlation, repeated-measures, ordinal-data, association-measure

I have ordinal data on happiness of citizens from multiple countries (from the European Value Study) and I have continuous data on the GDP per capita of multiple countries from the World Bank. Both of these variables are measured at multiple time points.

I want to test the hypothesis that countries with a low GDP per capita will see more of an increase in happiness with an increase in GDP per capita than countries that already have a high GDP per capita.

My first thought to approach this is that I need to make two groups; 1) countries with low GDP per capita, 2) countries with high GDP per capita. Then, for both groups I need to calculate the correlation between (change in) happiness and (change in) GDP per capita. Lastly, I need to compare the two correlations to check for a significant difference.

I am stuck however on how to approach the correlation analysis. For example, I dont know how to (and if I even have to) include the repeated measures of the different time points the data was collected. If I just base my correlations on one timepoint the data was measured, I feel like I am not really testing my research question, considering I am talking about an increase in happiness and an increase in GDP, which is a change over time.

If anyone has any suggestions on the right approach, I would be very thankful! Maybe I am overcomplicating it (wouldnt be the first time)!

Comment: You need a mixed model. You have to regress Happiness on GDP and let the slope (effect of GDP on happiness) be random (changing depending on the group). Then you can compare the effects between the groups.